# Why does this Python function not throw an error when Enum value is not matched?

Tags: python, enums

If I have a python function with the following `color` arg defined:

```
def search(
    self,
    color: ColorEnum = None
) -> Result:
```

And the `ColorEnum` looks like this:

```
class ColorEnum(str, Enum):
    Red = "red",
    Green = "green",
    Blue = "blue"
```

Why does Python not throw an error when I do the following:

```
search(color="black")
```

Is the Enum value merely used at compile time? It seems not to have any effect at run time and the function will work

Comment: You aren't using an Enum in that code at all, you're passing a string.  You've merely hinted that the expected type of that parameter is an Enum, it's not something that Python enforces.

Comment: Type hints aren't enforced at runtime; they are for the benefit of external tools like `mypy`. (They aren't really used at compile time, either, beyond saving annotations in a `dict` for runtime inspection, if desired.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function annotations are just "notes" you can attach to function parameters and the return type. They have no effect at runtime, though you can *access* them.

```
>>> def foo(x: int) -> str: pass
...
>>> foo.__annotations__
{'x': <class 'int'>, 'return': <class 'str'>}
```

If you *chose* to, you could use them to implement your own type-checking code:

```
def foo(x: int) -> str:
    if not isinstance(x, foo.__annotations__('x')):
        raise ValueError("x is not the right type")
    rv = str(x)
    if not isinstance(rv, foo.__annotations__('return')):
        raise ValueError("wrong return type")
    return rv
```

This is, of course, easily defeated, and is as likely to introduce bugs as to catch them.

Type hints provide documentation ("You *should* pass an `int` as an argument, and you *should* return a `str` value.") and a means for a *static* typechecker to catch obvious errors. Given the clean definition

```
def foo(x: int) -> str:
    return str(x)
```

a tool like `mypy` can flag code like the following as an error without having to *execute* the code:

```
foo("nine")  # "nine" does not have type int
3 + foo(5)   # foo returns a str, but you can't add int and str values
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.